# Sencha Touch 2.1.0 How to make list highly automatic increase

Tags: javascript, android, mobile, sencha-touch-2

The problem is due to the list need to have a high.
I hope it can automatically increase the height of the.
In 2.0.1 effect is what I need [SenchaTouch2.0.1Demo](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#hwcVL)
But now the project with 2.1.0
The effect is like this [SenchaTouch2.1.0Demo](http://new.senchafiddle.com/#/L4nGu/)
How can I use 2.1.0 achieve 2.0.1 effect

Comment: I'm not sure I understand...are you looking for a way to set the height of a component?

Comment: not setting the height, I hope it automatically adapt to, so that it can reveal all content.

Comment: So you're looking for a way that the height of the list varies based on the components inside it (more components means that it's taller)?

Comment: can you see the 2.1.0 demo? I have no set list height, that list can't display. But in 2.0.1 demo it works

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the **flex** property if you are using layout as **vbox** / **hbox**.

```
 items: [{
            title: 'tab1',
            scrollable: true,

            layout: 'vbox',

            items: [{

                flex:1,

                xtype: 'label',
                cls: 's-header',
                style: 'padding: 1em; text-align: center;',
                html: 'Header'
            },{
                flex:1,

                xtype: 'list',
                itemTpl: '{title}',
                scrollable: false,
                ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply.  But the viewing area is only half. I want like this [http://www.senchafiddle.com/#hwcVL](http://www.senchafiddle.com/#hwcVL)

Comment: Read more about **flex** here, it will solve your problem: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/guide/layouts